# Разница между Rotate и LocalEulerAngles в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotate

В чем принципиальная разница между `Rotate` и `LocalEulerAngles` в Unity? Пытаюсь настроить поворот камеры вверх/вниз (т.е. поворот вокруг оси Х) и не понимаю почему в случае с `Rotate` мы пише `_rotationX =`

```
_rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _rotationSensivity;
_rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, -60f, 60f);
_cameraTransform.transform.Rotate(_rotationX * (-1), 0f, 0f);
```

А в случае с `LocalEulerAngles` мы пишем `_rotationX -=` и при этом ещё `new Vector3`

```
_rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _rotationSensivity;
_rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(_rotationX, -60f, 60f);
_cameraTransform.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(_rotationX, 0f, 0f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Пришёл к выводу, что вот наиболее оптимальный вариант

```
private void RotateCameraUpDown()
    {
        _rotationX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _rotationSensivity;
        _cameraTransform.transform.localEulerAngles -= new Vector3(_rotationX, 0f, 0f);
    }
    private void RotateCameraLeftRight()
    {
        _rotationY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _rotationSensivity;
        transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3(0, _rotationY, 0f);
    }
```

Comment: В данном случае так пойдет, но в общем, если углы будут больше 360, падёт, и лучше юзать Rotate()

Answer (score -1):

Rotate вращает на заданные углы относительно текущего положения, а во втором случае ты задаешь вращение независимо от того, в каком положении объект был ранее

Comment: т.е. localeulerangles он относительно первоначальной локальной координаты ?

Грубо говоря ротейт каждый кадр перемещает на 1-3 градуса рывками, а localeulerangles как бы динамически вращает в каком-то диапазоне?

Comment: воспринимай  localeulerangles как состояние, поворот объекта,